# Minimizer on Sobolev space $H^1 (\Omega)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

I am trying to go to the next level in the calculus of variation of parameters, which is the minimization on Sobolev spaces. I come a cross this problem in which I stuck for how to attack it, could you please show me how to solve it.

For a bounded connected domains $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ with Lipschitz boundary, let $g \in L^2 (\Omega)$ and define the functional $J$ and function space $X$ by

$$J[u] = \int_\Omega \left\{ \frac{1}{2} \left| \nabla u(x) \right|^2 - g(x) u(x) \right\} dx,\quad X = \left\{ u \in H^1(\Omega); \int_\Omega u(x) dx=0 \right\}.$$

Show that the minimization problem $\inf_{u \in X} J[u]$ admits a unique minimizer $\overline u \in X$.

**My try**

Since $\Omega$ is bounded with Lischitz boundary, then (by Trace theorem) there exists a bounded linear operator $T: H^1(\Omega) \to L^p (\partial \Omega)$ such that

\begin{align}
    T u &= u\big|_{\partial \Omega}  &u \in H^1(\Omega) \cap C(\overline{\Omega})\\
    \| Tu\|_{L^p(\partial \Omega)} &\leq c(\Omega) \|u\|_{H^1 (\Omega)}), & u \in H^1(\Omega).
\end{align}
where $c$ a constant depends on $\Omega$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that, by Poincaré inequality (as $\Omega$ is bounded),
$$\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \le K\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$$
so that the norms
$$u \mapsto \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} + \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \quad \text{and} \quad u \mapsto \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$$
are equivalent on $X$ (and on $H^1(\Omega)$) so that we can choose the inner product in $X$ as
$$(u, v) = \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v.$$
Therefore,
$$J[u] = \frac{1}{2}\|u\|^2_X - \int gu.$$
Now let us show that the minimum of $J$ is well-defined. We have, by Hölder inequality,
\begin{align}
J[u] &\ge \frac{1}{2}\|u\|^2_X - \|g\|_{L^2}\|u\|_{L^2}\\
&\ge  \frac{1}{2}(\|u\|_X - \|g\|_{L^2})^2 - \frac{1}{2}\|g\|_{L^2}\\
&\ge - \frac{1}{2}\|g\|_{L^2}.
\end{align}
Now let us consider $m = \inf_{X}J[u]$ and $(u_n)_n \subset X$ such that
$$J[u_n] = m + \varepsilon_n \quad \text{with } \lim_n \varepsilon_n = 0.$$
By the paralllelogram law, we have
\begin{align}
\left\|\frac{u_n - u_m}{2}\right\|_X^2 &= \frac{1}{2}\|u_n\|_X^2 + \frac{1}{2}\|u_m\|_X^2 - \frac{1}{2}\left\|\frac{u_n + u_m}{2}\right\|_X^2\\
&= J[u_n] + J[u_m] - 2J[u_n + u_m]\\
&\le \varepsilon_n + \varepsilon_m
\end{align}
so that $(u_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in the Hilbert space $X$ (exercise: show that $X$ with this norm is an Hilbert space), hence there is $u \in X$ such that $\lim_n u_n = u$.

Now let us consider $t \in \mathbb R$ and $v \in X$. We have
\begin{align}
m \le J[u + tv] &= \frac{1}{2}\|u\|_X^2 - \int_\Omega gu + t(u, v) + \frac{t^2}{2}\|v\|^2_X - t\int_\Omega g v\\
&= J[u] + t(u, v) + \frac{t^2}{2}\|v\|^2_X - t\int_\Omega g v.
\end{align}
This implies,
$$(u, v) + \frac{t}{2}\|v\|^2_X - \int_\Omega g v\ge 0 \quad \forall t \in \mathbb R, \forall v \in X.$$
Therefore,
$$(u, v) = \int_\Omega gv$$
for all $v \in X$. This gives us uniqueness by considering $u_1, u_2 \in X$ two minimizers and setting $u = u_1 - u_2$ and $v = u_1 - u_2$ (details left as an exercise).

In fact this proof in more general: it shows that for an Hilbert space $X$ and a continuous linear map $\ell: H \to \mathbb R$, there exists a unique minimizer $u \in X$ to the functional
$$J[v] = \frac{1}{2}\|v\|^2_X - \ell(v)$$
and it satisfies
$$(u, v)_X = \ell(v).$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. However, I would like to ask some question?

1- Does the vectors that satisfy Poincare inequality need to be $ \forall u \in H^1(\Omega)$  with zero-trace (zero at the boundary)?

2- I think you missed (typo) an integration here! 

$$J[u] = \frac{1}{2}\|u\|^2_X - \int_\Omega g u\,dx.$$

3- After "By the paralllelogram law", either we delet the half on the right or we replace the equality by inequality. And the second step here does not make sense for me at all. Could you please explain it for me!

Comment: 1. No, Poincaré inequality is true for all $u \in H^1(\Omega).$ 2. Right! I've edited, thanks. 3. Yes indeed, there is an extra 1/2 on the rhs. For the second step, by linearity of the integral : 
$$\frac{1}{2}\|u_n\|_X^2 + \frac{1}{2}\|u_m\|_X^2 - \left\|\frac{u_n + u_m}{2}\right\|_X^2 = \frac{1}{2}\|u_n\|_X^2  - \int gu_n+ \frac{1}{2}\|u_m\|_X^2 - \int gu_m - 2\left(\frac{1}{2}\left\|\frac{u_n + u_m}{2}\right\|_X^2 -  \int g\frac{u_n + u_m}{2}\right)$$
which is what we sought.

Don't hesitate if you see anything else!

Comment: Honestly, I still not getting the uniqueness argument.

Comment: If $u_1, u_2$ are two minimizers, then 
$$(u_1 - u_2, v) = \int_\Omega (g - g) v = 0$$
for all $v$. Hence ... uniqueness.